# How to access recorded video in WP 8.1 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I used this instructions to capture a video
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452791.aspx

here is the part were the file is getting written to the app storage

```
var storageFile = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.CreateFileAsync("cameraCapture.mp4", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
await _mediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(_profile, storageFile);
```

How I can access the file on an other page of the app. 
I want to play this video within a MediaElement (VideoLeinwand)

```
var stream = ???

VideoLeinwand.AutoPlay = true;
VideoLeinwand.SetSource(stream, ???);
VideoLeinwand.Play();
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly and you have succeded in recording a file *cameraCapture.mp4*, then you should be able to play it for example like this:

```
StorageFile mediafile = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFileAsync("cameraCapture.mp4");
var stream = await mediafile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
VideoLeinwand.SetSource(stream, mediafile.ContentType);
VideoLeinwand.Play();
```